# Is there a tree-like structure where nodes can appear multiple times and even be ancestors of themselves?

Tags: java, tree, web-crawler

I'm crawling some web pages, recursively getting all the existing links, and I would like to preserve in some kind of structure the history of links I've had to visit to get to each link. This means it's possible to find the same link multiple times in the process.

I already store the links in a `Set` to make sure I don't visit the same link more than once, but probably this is not the right kind of structure to keep the history

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific about what you're looking for.  Mathematically, a tree is a kind of graph, and general graphs can contain loops, so maybe you're looking for some kind of graph.  But I'm not sure what it means for a node to appear multiple times.  How is it just one node if it appears multiple times?  Or if you mean that multiple nodes can carry the same value, then is that really what you want in support of your project?  It sounds like that would get in the way more than it would help.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, I guess, using your words, I need to have multiple nodes contain the same value and have the same descendants

Comment: I think the `directed graph` should be the more apropriate data structure.

Comment: Let me say again: you claim to have among your objectives to avoid visiting the same URL multiple times, and your idea to have multiple nodes containing the same URL is very likely to get in the way of that.  Are you *sure*?  What purpose is served?  But that's a detail of how you use the data structure, not a characteristic of the data structure itself.  Any way around, the generalization you're looking for is a graph, presumably a directed one to match the directed nature of hyperlinks.  You might need to augment that with, say, an index.

Comment: This example shows your same problem: [Graphs](https://youtu.be/gXgEDyodOJU?t=639)

Comment: *"but probably this is not the right kind of structure"*: why not? What is the problem you have? You'll need to be much more specific as to what results you expect and how you have a problem in getting that result (provide code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by John Bollinger

> Any way around, the generalization you're looking for is a graph, presumably a directed one to match the directed nature of hyperlinks. You might need to augment that with, say, an index.

That's what I was looking for at the time of the question. It's not what I used in the end, though. Turns out keeping all the links, info and references can be quite heavy on the memory